# Factory class - using a IOC container to register and resolve types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, factory-pattern

I am not quite sure how to implement this, or what the best strategy is, basically I have an (MVC) controller

```
public TestController(IService1 service1, IService2 service2,...)
{ }
```

(At the moment there are only 2 parameters, but could increase).

My idea was that I would create a service factory class, so instead of having a parameter for each service we can instead have one for the factory and then get whatever services we need

```
private IService1 _service1;
public TestController(IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
{
    // this could also be called from a separate action, 
    // so we only get it when we need it
    _service1 = serviceFactory.Get<IService1>();
}
```

Now my service factory implementation is a bit rubbish, essentially I just have a dictionary that caches all of the registered services and the types:

```
/// <summary>
/// Service factory class
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Only one instance of this class should be created during the lifetime of the application
/// </remarks>
public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Locking object
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of mappings
    /// </summary>
    private IDictionary<string, Func<IService>> _mappings;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ServiceFactory()
    {
        _mappings = new Dictionary<string, Func<IService>>();
        registerMappings();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a service from the factory
    /// </summary>
    public T GetService<T>() where T : IService
    {
        if (_mappings.Count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("There are no mappings");

        lock (_lock)
        {
            var typeName = typeof(T).Name;
            if (_mappings.ContainsKey(typeName))
                return (T)_mappings[typeName]();

            return default(T);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register the mappings needed for this service factory
    /// </summary>
    private void registerMappings()
    {
        register<IService1>(() => new Service1())
             .register<IService2>(() => new Service2())
             .
             .
             .register<IServiceN>(() => new ServiceN());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register the service classes
    /// </summary>
    private ServiceFactory register<T>(Func<IService> mapping) where T : IService
    {
        var type = typeof(T).Name;
        if (!_mappings.ContainsKey(type))
            _mappings.Add(type, mapping);

        return this;
    }
}
```

My question is, can I use an IOC container in the service factory and let it deal with the registering and resolving of types?? Is this a good approach?

OR could I have a more fundamental problem, do I need a service factory, should I be using one?

It just be a simple matter that my MVC controller needs refactoring, i.e. I can try and adhere to one controller for each service??

Just want some tips on what the best approach is here, I am still a rookie when it comes to DI/factory pattern/some-other-pattern etc :)

Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to build your own IoC container. You wouldn't need your factory when using an IoC container.

Comment: It might be helpful to think of Dependency Injection as *"passing dependencies into the class constructor."*  If you think of it that way, all this might become clearer.  IoC containers are really just a lot of ceremony for this simple mechanism.  So if your scenario is compatible with the idea of writing a class that takes some interface as a parameter, and then providing some implementation of that interface to the class on construction, then it is potentially a good candidate for IoC.

Comment: I wouldn't add an extra layer of complexity here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the general advice is that you should try to adhere to the single-responsibility principle, which in your case can be interpreted as keeping your controllers relatively small and focused in what they do. That way, the number of service dependencies will be small and passing all the required services should not be a nuisance.

That said, sometimes it can be useful to provide a single access point for several services, to reduce the number of parameters being passed around, or to allow interaction between the services themselves (IoC containers don't like circular relationships/dependencies).

I have had need for the latter and decided to create a UnitOfWork class that provided access to all of the services trough properties. The UnitOfWork takes all of the services as constructor parameters and is in turn passed as constructor parameter to the controllers. This allows the whole chain (services, uow and controller) to be constructed and injected via IoC, and if you keep object construction cost low (by avoiding doing much work in the constructors) then the performance overhead will be minimal.

In pragmatic terms, both solutions will be fine. However, there is greater risk of spaghettifying your code with the second approach, as it will be unclear which services are used where.

Comment: +1. I absolutely agree. The use of the `IServiceFactory` just smells like the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) and all my spider-SOLID-senses are tinkling here. The OP should probably group those related services together in an [aggregate service](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) or perhaps the [command pattern](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).